# Query is Not Updateable - Join Key is Not in Recordset

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am unable to add new records to this query. It is set up such that table "SOL_Routing" is a many to many, meaning only the combination of fields [PartID], [WC_ID], and [Operation] can uniquely identify a record because all 3 of these fields need to allow duplicate values. The same combination of these 3 fields should not exist twice.
[image]

Example of query data set:

```
Part_No    Operation    Workcenter
X          1            WC1
X          2            WC1
X          3            WC2
Y          1            WC1
Y          2            WC4
Y          3            WC7
```

How can I change the keys or arrange my data differently to allow me to add new records to this query? I do not want to loose referential integrity by changing the Recordset type to "Inconsistent Updates". The whole purpose of the query is to add the new record to SOL_Routings by being able to enter "[Workcenter]" and "[Part_No]" names through the joined ID.

Comment: Where's your form and code to select the Part numbers and Workcenter? Your tables are fine. You just need the combo boxes to hide the key ID fields, display the text, and then append the data using the combo box values in field 1.

Comment: Have you defined relational integrity in your Access database? You can find this in the Relationships button, usually under the Database Tools menu. If you see the relationships you desire for the three tables above, your work is done. The database will automatically enforce relational integrity for you. You won't need the `Workcenters` and `PM_Parts` tables in the query, if all you are trying to do is ensure the foreign keys exist.